# Can't bind a function to a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I can't seem to bind my function to this certain button. I have tried this:

This is my function:

```
def callback(str):
    print('he button <%s> is being pressed' % str)
```

and this is where i bind the function:

```
btn = Button(text="%s" % feedList[i]['message'])
btn.bind(on_press=callback(i))
```

Comment: is `i` a string? because `callback()` needs a string as an argument.

Comment: no, but i tried returning a string but it still wont run e.g. on_press=callback("hello world")

Comment: You should give us more information then, especially the error messages you get and a code we can run and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [should](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#module-kivy.uix.button) pass function name when binding:

```
btn.bind(on_press=callback)

# ...

def callback(instance, value):
    print('My button <%s> state is <%s>' % (instance, value))
```

---

If you want to pass `i` to callback also you [can use](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) `partial` function:

```
from functools import partial

btn.bind(on_press=partial(callback, i))

# ...

def callback(i, instance, value):
    print('My button <%s> state is <%s>' % (instance, value))
```

Comment: can i ask you another question?